# Drools building KieBase programmatically not working in Windows

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server

We have a fairly large set of rules which are templated and the KieBase is created programmatically. This is the case for both Stateful and stateless sessions.

These rules when executed as unit tests work on Mac os but not in Windows.

The project to reproduce this issue is here: [Test project](https://github.com/manjunath-sp/drools-reproducer-kie-module-model/blob/master/com.drools.test.kie.file.system/src/test/java/com/drools/test/com/drools/test/kie/file/system/DroolsSessionUtil.java) (Look under src/test/java for the utility to create KieSession)

If would be helpful if you anyone explains what I am missing.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting some compilation errors? An empty Kbase? Exceptions?

Comment: There were no compile errors, for stateless sessions rules were not executed. For stateful session, global variables were not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
private static final String OUTPUT_DRL_PREFIX = "src" + File.separator + "main" + File.separator + "resources" ...;

KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

String outFile = OUTPUT_DRL_PREFIX + "result" + DRL;
kfs.write(outFile, rules );
```

The KieFileSystem isn't a Windows file system. It isn't going to change it's idea of a name separator when the application is running on some operating system or other.

Simply use

```
static final String KIE_SEP = '/';
```